# How to format ag-grid Pie chart labels

Tags: javascript, charts, formatting, ag-grid

I'm able to create and configure the series of a Pie chart using the following code:

```
    createPieChart() {
      this.options.series = [{ 
        type: 'pie', 
        labelKey: 'os',
        angleKey: 'share',
        label: { enabled: true }, 
      }]
      this.options.legend = { enabled: false }
    },
```

The labels appear like so, which means that if the label is too long it overflows both onto the chart itself and over the sides of the div it's being contained within:

[image]

I am aiming to make it so that if the label has more than 5 characters then it would only show 3 characters and the following symbols: ...

**So for example, the label 'Symbian qwerfrwf wfegewdfv fewdf feewdf' for the blue section of the pie chart above would only show 'Sym...'**

I know how to do this for column and bar charts where we use a formatter

```
     label: {
        formatter: (params) => {
          if (params.value.length > 5) {
            return params.value.substr(0, 3) + '...';
          }
          return params.value;
        },
      }
```

However, for a pie chart there doesn't seem to be a formatter available in the documentation (API Reference) (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-charts-pie-series/)

How can I achieve the style I want for pie chart labels?

Comment: I'm similarly having problems with my ag-Chart donut chart labels looking terrible, so I wanted to try to change their z-index or otherwise change their appearance. What did you figure out?

Comment: You can see my problem at https://plnkr.co/edit/Lm5PAvLkE5cJBGVi when you make the window narrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
legend: {
            enabled: true,
            item:{
              label:{
                formatter:(params)=>{
                  console.log('id',params.id)
                  console.log('itemId',params.itemId)
                  console.log('value',params.value)
                  return 'my legend goes here'
                }
              }
            }
          },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).